# R -- Always grab the last day of the previous year in R

Tags: r, date

I am an aspiring data scientist, and this will be my first ever question on StackOF.

I have this line of code to help wrangle me data. My date filter is static. I would prefer not to have to go in an change this hardcoded value every year. What is the best alternative for my date filter to make it more dynamic? The date column is also difficult to work with because it is not a 
"date", it is a "dbl"

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# create a sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
    DATE = c(20191230, 20191231, 20200122)
)
```

Tried so far:

```
df %>%
    filter(DATE >= 20191231)
```

Comment: Hey @72o can you please make a reproducible example, so we can better help you?

Comment: You should add `library(<something>)` at the top of your snippet for anything not provided by a vanilla install of R. Is `tbl` provided with the base R? It seems not, and I have no idea what it is, nor `%>%`.

Comment: When I try to just run ````library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyquant)'''' ''''tbl(con, in_schema("INSDLIB", "POLPRHSP")) %>%
    mutate(PHUSRDT = ymd(PHUSRDT))```` I get the following error ````Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1374: 42S02: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - YMD in *LIBL type *N not found.````

Comment: As stated below as well. This error is not related to your question (but to the database connection).

Answer (score 0):

```
# load packages (lubridate for dates)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# create a sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
    DATE = c(20191230, 20191231, 20200122)
)
```

This looks like this:

```
      DATE
1 20191230
2 20191231
3 20200122

# and now...
df %>% # take the dataframe
    mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE)) %>% # turn the DATE column actually into a date
    filter(DATE >= floor_date(Sys.Date(), "year") - days(1))
```

...and filter rows where `DATE` is `>=` to one day before the first day of this year (`floor_date(Sys.Date(), "year")`)

```
        DATE
1 2019-12-31
2 2020-01-22
```

Comment: This is the error message I receive when I try that script...Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1374: 42S02: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - YMD in *LIBL type *N not found.

Comment: I updated the answer. Is it ok if I edit your question to include a minimal working example? Then it would be valid question.

Comment: And your Error is about the database connection not about the date.